# How to fix "401 Unauthorized" error in PUT Invoke-RestMethod (trying to replace stored procedure)

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-powershell

I'm trying to manage CosmosDB resources using REST API and PowerShell.
My code works fine when I use GET and POST, but when I try to replace an existing object using PUT, I get 401 error.

My code registers stored procedure when it doesn't exist and should update it when the SP already exists.

So when I create a new SP, I use the following variables:

```
$Verb = "POST"
$ResourceType = "sprocs"
$ResourceLink = "dbs/$DBName/colls/$CollName"
$queryUri = "$CosmosDBEndPoint$ResourceLink/$ResourceType"
```

get auth header:

```
...
$authHeader = Generate-MasterKeyAuthorizationSignature -verb $Verb -resourceLink $ResourceLink -resourceType $ResourceType -key $MasterKey -keyType "master" -tokenVersion "1.0" -dateTime $dateTime
```

and then call REST method:

```
$header = @{authorization=$authHeader;"x-ms-version"="2017-02-22";"x-ms-date"=$dateTime} 
$contentType= "application/json"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method $Verb -ContentType $contentType -Uri $queryUri -Headers $header -Body $body
```

It works great and creates what it should.
And, when I need to replace existing object (SP in my case), I change variables like this:

```
$Verb = "PUT"
$ResourceType = "sprocs"
$ResourceLink = "dbs/$DBName/colls/$CollName"
$ItemName = "SP_Name"
$queryUri = "$CosmosDBEndPoint$ResourceLink/$ResourceType/$ItemName"
```

generate auth header just like in case with POST (only verb is different):

```
...
$authHeader = Generate-MasterKeyAuthorizationSignature -verb $Verb -resourceLink $ResourceLink -resourceType $ResourceType -key $MasterKey -keyType "master" -tokenVersion "1.0" -dateTime $dateTime
...
```

and the invoke REST method with new URI (which includes now  name of SP to be changed):

```
$header = @{authorization=$authHeader;"x-ms-version"="2017-02-22";"x-ms-date"=$dateTime} 
$contentType= "application/json"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method $Verb -ContentType $contentType -Uri $queryUri -Headers $header -Body $body
```

Which is throws me `401 Unauthorized`, so it seems that auth header isn't right. Can't figure out what I should change there.

Answer (score 0):

From here it looks like the resource or the value in the resource you are trying to change does not support a PUT action. You can confirm manually;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/

or by going to;

https://resources.azure.com/

Comment: Actually, it should: [Replace a Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/replace-a-stored-procedure) and seemingly does.

Answer (score 0):

So the key was to change variables this way:

```bsh
$ResourceType = "sprocs"
$ItemName = "SP_Name"
$ResourceLink = "dbs/$DBName/colls/$CollName/$ResourceType/$ItemName"
```

and then generate auth header.
I.e. resource link variable must contain the full path to the replaced object.